# How to change file name of my email attachment in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an image attachment in my application, it works properly, an email attachment appears in mail. Now this attachment comes with random image file name. I want image name to be different every time with particular naming convention with sender name and current time. How can I do that??

This is the onClick method on my save and send button. When I press this button, Image is getting saved in my gallery with naming convention I want. Below portion is send part using implicit intent. Guide me whether I can add name of the image as I want in attached image in email.

Thank you in advance.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    encodedImage.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = encodedImage.getDrawingCache();
    saveImage(bmap); //my method which saves my bitmap image in my gallery.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String receiverEmail = receiver.getText().toString().trim();
    String to[] = {receiverEmail};
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.setType("imge/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello wats up");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri); //bitmap uri created by a function and working properly.
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do that?

You are invoking a third-party email client, using some incorrect code (`ACTION_SEND` supports either `EXTRA_TEXT` *or* `EXTRA_STREAM`; do not assume that everyone will support *both*). That email app is welcome to name the attachment whatever it wants.

The best you can do is supply a `Uri` that has a "particular naming convention with sender name and current time" for the filename segment, and then hope that the email app actually uses that filename segment for the attachment name.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a `ContentProvider` that can be queried and supports the columns in [`OpenableColumns`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/OpenableColumns.html). If present, `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` is used by most email clients to derive the file name.

Of course the `ContentProvider` also has to return the file contents when being opened as a stream.

The default implementation of [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) might already do what you want.